# I m looking for trigger in oracle with if-else and elseif statement here is my code

Tags: triggers, oracle10g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER yindel_str_change   
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON yindel   
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    IF (NEW.one > 0) 
      THEN  update yindel set one=one+1 where name='1'; 
    ELSE dbms_output.put_line('  Difference '); 
    END IF; 
  END;
```

Comment: that´s `pl/sql` but definitely not `java`

Comment: Java tag not applicable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER yindel_str_change
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF yindel_a, yindel_b
   ON wholedata
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF :NEW.yindel_a = '1' AND :NEW.yindel_b = '1'
   THEN
      UPDATE yindel
         SET one = one + 1
       WHERE name = '1';
   ELSE
      IF :NEW.yindel_a = '1' AND :NEW.yindel_b = '2'
      THEN
         UPDATE yindel
            SET two = two + 1
          WHERE name = '1';
      ELSE
         IF :NEW.yindel_a = '2' AND :NEW.yindel_b = '2'
         THEN
            UPDATE yindel
               SET two = two + 1
             WHERE name = '2';
         ELSE
            UPDATE yindel
               SET two = two + 0
             WHERE name = '2';
         END IF;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Is it the solution you used